# Why is my code not writing to file?

Tags: java, android, file, file-io, fileinputstream

I am trying to read an integer from a text file when my activity starts. 
In my log, I only see

**DEBUG: Attempt to read High Score File**

and never

**DEBUG: Reading High Score File**

or

**DEBUG: Could not read high score file**

Why is my file being created by writeHighScore file but no value is being written to it.

```
public class GameScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Simon simon = new Simon();;
private int score = 0;
private int highScore = 0;
private String highScoreString;
private String FILENAME = "highscore.txt";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_screen);

    //Read highScore file
    TextView highScoreTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.high_score_tv);

    Log.i("DEBUG", "Attempt to read High Score File");

    try{
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fis);
        if(scanner.hasNext()){
            Log.i("DEBUG", "Reading High Score File");
            highScoreString = scanner.nextLine();
            highScore = Integer.getInteger(highScoreString);
        }
        scanner.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        Log.e("READ ERROR", "Could not read high score: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    highScoreTV.setText(""+highScore);
}
```

**writeHighScore**

```
private void writeHighScore(){
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
            Log.i("DEBUG", "Writing High Score File");
            pw.println("" + score + "\n");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("WRITE ERROR", "Cannot Save: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(GameScreen.this, "Error Saving", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like your file is empty.

Comment: Where is your code that wrote to the same file?

Comment: Could you show us what's in that file as well?

Comment: You want `Integer.parseInt(highScoreString)` and not `Integer.getInteger(highScoreString)`. `getInteger` is used for system properties according to the docs

Comment: Added my writeHighScore method, I check my file and it looks like it is empty although I got the log message "DEBUG: Writing High Score File"

So it seems I am writing to file incorrectly. The file does exist but it is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you forgot to close the print writer, therefore the file can't be opened by the reader.

Simply adding a closing statement to your `writeHighScore` method should resolve the issue.

Comment: This was the solution! 

This is my second time dealing with file io and I guess I missed that part while copying over from my old code.